WSL: not found related errors regardless of the command & Bash prompt only with hostname
[Issue that I'm facing]
I'm encountering an issue with my Bash prompt in WSL, where instead of the usual format (e.g., username@hostname:~$), however, it's displaying only hostname:~$ instead. It used to show up with the username and the @ symbol, however, I was facing issues not being able to use apt-get update or apt-get upgrade commands because I couldn't figure out my password.
So I tried multiple different things and decided to reinstall everything so that I could start fresh, but I think that might have backfired as I'm only seeing this format: "hostname:~$."
In an attempt to resolve the issue, I tried checking with ChatGPT, which suggested me to use multiple different commands like nano ~/.bashrc but I would get this: -sh: nano: not found.
[Troubleshooting]
Command: wsl -l -v
Result:
PS C:\Users\username> wsl -l -v
NAME                STATE           VERSION
* docker-desktop    Stopped         2
Ubuntu              Stopped         2

I also would like to add that the color of the Bash prompt is white instead of green.
Would someone please help guide me on what I need to do to resolve the issue...?

what is the ouput of "wsl -l -v" in powershell

@nabinsademba Thank you so much for checking my question!! I edited my posted question!

did you do :
wsl --unregister Ubuntu  &
wsl --install -d Ubuntu
to uninstall and reinstall
if not please do above and set wsl --set-default Ubuntu and check once

@nabinsademba Thank you so much for helping me! This worked!!

its my pleasure :)
